# Unpacking a list in python using split()

Tags: python

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/files/')
for f in os.listdir():
    file_name,file_ext=os.path.splitext(f)
    print(file_name,file,ext)
```

**Output**:

```
earth - our solar system - #4 .mp4
pluto - our solar system - #5 .mp4
jupiter - our solar system - #1 .mp4
venus - our solar system - #3 .mp4
mars - our solar system - #2 .mp4
```

The above code works just fine, but I have an error when I add the last two lines of code

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/malbairmani/Desktop/rt')
for f in os.listdir():

    file_name,file_ext=os.path.splitext(f)
    print(file_name,file_ext)
    x,y,z= file_name.split('-')
    print(x,y,z)
```

**Output:**

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

But, If I type `x=file_spilt('-')`, it works just fine

Comment: Do you have any other file listed as output, in your first example? Looks like there are more files and you are showing us just some part of it.

Comment: No , I only have these five files in my folder @Asocia

Comment: I copied your output, tried to split them by `-` and assigned them to `x, y, z`. It didn't give me any error.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there are no `'-'` in the string, adding `.split('-')` to it will not return an error, it will just store the whole string into a list.

Comment: But, I want to store each value of the list on a different variable ```x,y,z= file_name.split('-') ``` I tried this but it did not work

Comment: Can you `print(file_name.split('-'))` right before unpacking and give me the result?

Comment: I got this ```['earth ', ' our solar system ', ' #4']
['pluto ', ' our solar system ', ' #5']
['jupiter ', ' our solar system ', ' #1']
['venus ', ' our solar system ', ' #3']
['mars ', ' our solar system ', ' #2']``` @Ann Zen

Comment: Try `x,y,z= file_name.split('-')[0], file_name.split('-')[1],, file_name.split('-')[2],`